# Unable to remove trash icon from favourites

Tags: gnome, .desktop, 20.10

[image: My Desktop]

Unable to remove trash icon from favourites column.

Comment: Why do you want to and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the trash icon from the dock:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash false
```

Answer (score 1):

try going into properties of dock,
right click on the icon and you will get the option to remove it.

Comment: Worked like a Charm!

Comment: Please elaborate a little on your answer for the benefit of future readers. How do you go into properties? Where to look? Is this applicable for a standard Ubuntu install?

Comment: Settings > Ubuntu Desktop > Dock > Configure dock behavior > disable 'Show Trash' (https://askubuntu.com/a/1446032/854911)