# Removing "Rubbish Bin" from Ubuntu Dock on 21.10

Tags: ubuntu-dock, 21.10

I would like to remove the new "Rubbish Bin" entry that has been added to the Ubuntu Dock on 21.10. I can't see any settings anywhere or any other way of removing it.

Is there maybe a dconf setting I can tweak?

Comment: If you right-click it what are the options?

Comment: I'm not OP but if I right click, an empty pop-up menu comes up in the upper left corner of the screen, this menu never disappears and remains in the foreground even when you switch apps, the only way to get rid of it is to restart the computer. This makes it quite urgent for me to be able to remove it, as I'm afraid I might be right-clicking it by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trash icon on the dock was broken for me, if I right clicked on it, an empty pop-up menu would come up in the upper left corner of the screen, this menu would remain in the foreground even when switching apps (I had to log out to get rid of it)

Luckily, it was easy to get rid of the rubbish bin icon, I just had to type in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-trash false
```

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks! Also FYI you can get rid of that broken context menu by doing `Alt+F2` and typing `r` to reset the gnome shell session.

Comment: thank you @tom-james-watson indeed I was going to search on the web if there was a way to reset the session but then I found the command above

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Ubuntu Desktop > Dock > Configure dock behavior > disable 'Show Trash'